# R - Calculate Time Elapsed Since Last Events with Multiple Event Types and IDs

Tags: r, loops, datatables

Similar questions have been asked before where the question is how to calculate the number of observations since an event. I have a further request. How to calculate the number of days since the same type of observation but also to find the number of days since any other type of event. I also have ids.

To illustrate please see below. I am trying to do this in R using Datatables but to little result.

What I have:

```
  date     event  id
2000-07-06     2  1
2000-07-07     1  1
2000-07-09     0  1
2000-07-10     0  1
2000-07-15     2  1
2000-07-16     1  1
2000-07-20     0  1
2000-07-21     1  1
2000-07-06     1  2
2000-07-07     2  2
2000-07-15     0  2
2000-07-16     0  2
2000-07-17     2  2
2000-07-18     1  2
```

and what I would like to have is as follows:

```
  date     event  id days_since_event_1 days_since_event_2
2000-07-06     2  1        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     1  1        NA                 1
2000-07-09     0  1        2                  3
2000-07-10     0  1        3                  4
2000-07-15     2  1        8                  9
2000-07-16     1  1        9                  1
2000-07-20     0  1        4                  5
2000-07-21     1  1        5                  6
2000-07-06     1  2        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     2  2        1                  NA
2000-07-15     0  2        9                  8
2000-07-16     0  2        10                 9
2000-07-17     2  2        11                 10
2000-07-18     1  2        12                 1
```

The two events are mutually exclusive, that is, they cannot take place on the same day. 
Hope to hear some good advice. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses the `Chron` Library to calculate difference in the dates

```
library(chron)

df$date <- chron(as.character(df$date),format=c(date="y-m-d"))

for(j in unique(df$id)){
  DaysSince1 <-NA
  DaysSince2 <-NA
  RowsWithID <- grep(j,df$id)

  for(i in RowsWithID){
    df$days_since_event_1[i] <- df$date[i]-df$date[i-DaysSince1]
    df$days_since_event_2[i] <- df$date[i]-df$date[i-DaysSince2]

    if(df$event[i]==1){DaysSince1<-1}
      else{DaysSince1<-DaysSince1+1}

    if(df$event[i]==2){DaysSince2<-1}
      else{DaysSince2<-DaysSince2+1}
  }
}
```

This code gives the following results

```
> df
       date event id days_since_event_1 days_since_event_2
1  00-07-06     2  1                 NA                 NA
2  00-07-07     1  1                 NA                  1
3  00-07-09     0  1                  2                  3
4  00-07-10     0  1                  3                  4
5  00-07-15     2  1                  8                  9
6  00-07-16     1  1                  9                  1
7  00-07-20     0  1                  4                  5
8  00-07-21     1  1                  5                  6
9  00-07-06     1  2                 NA                 NA
10 00-07-07     2  2                  1                 NA
11 00-07-15     0  2                  9                  8
12 00-07-16     0  2                 10                  9
13 00-07-17     2  2                 11                 10
14 00-07-18     1  2                 12                  1
```

---

To address you comment, you can do the following in `Base R` to get the number of observations rather than days. No Libraries needed.

```
for(j in unique(df$id)){
  ObsSince1 <-NA
  ObsSince2 <-NA
  RowsWithID <- grep(j,df$id)

  for(i in RowsWithID){
    df$Obs_since_event_1[i] <- ObsSince1
    df$Obs_since_event_2[i] <- ObsSince2

    if(df$event[i]==1){ObsSince1<-1}
    else{ObsSince1<-ObsSince1+1}

    if(df$event[i]==2){ObsSince2<-1}
    else{ObsSince2<-ObsSince2+1}
  }
}
```

You should get the following output

```
> df
         date event id Obs_since_event_1 Obs_since_event_2
1  2000-07-06     2  1                NA                NA
2  2000-07-07     1  1                NA                 1
3  2000-07-09     0  1                 1                 2
4  2000-07-10     0  1                 2                 3
5  2000-07-15     2  1                 3                 4
6  2000-07-16     1  1                 4                 1
7  2000-07-20     0  1                 1                 2
8  2000-07-21     1  1                 2                 3
9  2000-07-06     1  2                NA                NA
10 2000-07-07     2  2                 1                NA
11 2000-07-15     0  2                 2                 1
12 2000-07-16     0  2                 3                 2
13 2000-07-17     2  2                 4                 3
14 2000-07-18     1  2                 5                 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have now discovered that I am actually not interested in the number of days between each event but rather the number of observations. Do you have a fix? or maybe this is simply a whole other question to be posted here on stack exchange.

Comment: I've edited my response to include a "fix" for your new problem. Please consider marking marking this as answered if it works for your needs,

Answer (score 2):

You could subset your Dates for all with a specific event encoding, e.g.:

```
date.2 = DATAFRAME[which(DATAFRAME[,2]==2),1]
```

and then just do

```
DATAFRAME[which(DATAFRAME[,2]==2),5] = as.numeric(diff.Date(date.2))
```

and so on.
Possibly this is even easier to do, but this was the first thing coming to my mind.
DATAFRAME is just the name of your dataframe here.

edit: If I see it correctly you want NAs wherever ID and event column are different to each other? Then you could just go on with:
DATAFRAME[which(DATAFRAME[,2] != DATAFRAME[,3]),c(4,5)] = NA or something like that

Comment: Hi, yes the NAs would occur because there has not been a preceding event for that ID. I have realised I have typed out the question wrong and I don't need the number of days between observations but rather the number of observations between each event.